# ASP.NET Membership Provider and how to soft delete an account?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I am using MVC3, EF5, C#, Sql Server 2008 R2.

I am using the Membership Provider in conjunction with some "Organisation" tables of my own with a link table to the membership tables.

When I Cancel an account in my application I do a soft delete which is fine for my tables. However I am unsure what I should do with the membership records for the account in question. Ideally I would want to soft delete the records as well.

The problem is that when I try to create a new account using the same username as a cancelled account, I get a "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name." type error.

Obviously I could hard delete the membership user, but this would mean me hard deleting all the related records in my application which I do not wish to do.

Thoughts.

Thanks.

Comment: What membership provider do you use - new universal membership provider or legacy membership provider?

Comment: Errrr. Legacy I guess.I have tables like aspnet_Membership etc. Did I make the wrong choice?

Comment: I assume a "soft delete" is just `IsDeleted = true` in a column somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default membership provider requires a unique user name, you could prefix the user name with something so multiple users could have the same name, or modify a user name on soft deletion to include some prefix so it could be reused. Neither or which are particularly nice if I'm honest, but unless you add your own 'display name' field your stuck with the constraint.

Comment: Yes, interesting workarounds. Probably best to prefix username on soft-delete. I have since read an article on the wisdom of using soft deletes as opposed to triggers/archive DBs, so may now change in the medium term.

Comment: What I've done in the past is to set the membership provider's username to a guid and use an email address for identification, they have to be unique anyway, then you can have a display name that allows duplicates. it requires a little but of fiddling but its not too difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a custom membership provider and override the [`DeleteUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.deleteuser.aspx) method and perform whatever logic you need.

Answer (score 1):

You are using legacy ASP.Net Membership Provider which uses store procedure. It is good news for your case, because it are a lot easy to modify than new New Universal Provider which uses Entity Framework.

Easiest way is to create a table to keep track of deleted users. *(you might have created it already according to your question.)*

[image]

Then you want to modify **aspnet_Users_DeleteUser** store procedure to

- insert UserId to DeletedUsers table instead of deleting user.
- alter username and email to something like appending GUID at the end (*so that user with same username and email address can register again)*.

Also update **aspnet_Membership** table's **IsApproved** column to false to prevent login using that username again.

Comment: Very helpful thanks. I did implement Tom's prefix idea which works fine, but your answer is so helpful as well... So all of the above are answers !!! So will pick Tom's as he was in first. But a huge thank you anyway.